# Kernel trick and its inner-product kernel

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

I try to solve a task where a nonlinear transformation $\phi:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ is given by $\phi(x)=(a_0\cdot 1,a_1\cdot x,a_2\cdot x^2,\ldots,a_d\cdot x^d)$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

My inner-product kernel $k(x,y):=\phi(x)^T\cdot\phi(y)$ is given.

At first I tried to transform it into a matrix:

$k(x,y)=\phi(x)^T\cdot\phi(y)=\begin{pmatrix}1\cdot a_0\\x\cdot a_1\\x^2\cdot a_2\\\vdots\\x^da_d\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1\cdot a_0 & y\cdot a_1 & y^2\cdot a_2 & \cdots & y^da_d\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
  a_0^2 & y^1a_0a_1 & \cdots & y^da_0a_d\\
  x^1a_1a_0 & x^1y^1a_1^2 & \cdots\\
  x^2a_2a_0 &         & \ddots\\
  \vdots\\
  x^da_da_0 & x^dy^1a_da_1 & \cdots & x^dy^da_d^2
\end{pmatrix}$

The first task to solve was to determine $k$ for all $a_i=1$ which is pretty straight forward for the matrix representation.

On the second task I have to find the $a_i$ s.t. $k(x,y)=(1+x\cdot y)^d$ and compare the results with the inner product kernel in a).

For this task several questions appeared in my mind:

- how to determine a non matrix representation from a matrix?
- when I am able to determine what part of the question isn't correct - how can actually determine the $a_i$?
- is  there a real application for this task - like when you have to linearly non separable sets and you need to use the kernel trick to make them linearly separable, is there a reason to determine a certain choice of $a_i$ to let $k(x,y)$ represent a certain function $\Rightarrow$ if yes, which functions could $k(x,y)$ represent?

Comment: You'll take $\phi(x),\phi(y)$ as $(d+1)\times 1$ vectors, so the inner product will be a number, not a matrix.

Comment: Could you maybe expand your comment and tell me how exactly I should compute the product what it is meant to be (guessing you proposing to interpret the product as cross product?)

Comment: You compute the product same way, i.e. inner product. When $\phi$'s are vertical vectors, i.e. (d+1)x1, the product $\phi(x)^T\phi(y)$ will be $1\times1$, a number.